# Is table prefixing controlled by db_set_active()?

Tags: 7

If I use `db_set_active()` to fetch data from another database, how will that affect table prefixing?

Is table prefixing dynamic in the sense that it adjusts to the currently active database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `db_set_active` you change the config that Drupal uses, so in theory you could use `db_set_active` to use the same database but change the prefix used.

Drupal will use the configuration defined, and the changed they imply.

You should note, that db_set_active won't work if you use multiple db backends for older Drupal versions (Drupal 6 and earlier, several MySQL backends are fine, but you can't switch from PgSQL to MySQL)

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question. I won't be using different database types, but I need to connect to a legacy database which does not use prefixes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @googeltorp -- I had to re-read your answer a few times to be sure I understood part of your answer. My understanding is that the db_* functions are helper functions for the current active database (or 'default' db basically). If you have mysql and sqlite as defined configurations you need to use Database::getConnection and use PDO more directly (without db_* API usage -- SelectQuery() etc are all still ok ... This is seen alot by users of the Migrate module ... I dont care so much for the verbiage "db_set_active wont work" ... that part of the DB API is simply not designed that way.

Comment: Note that different databases are working just fine beside each other in D7. That's only a problem in 6.x